# How to Create a Http Server with TCP Server Sockets in C++/QT

Tags: c++, qt, httpserver, tcpserver, simplehttpserver

I want to create a Http Server to send an MJPEG Stream. In the first place i therefore want to create a Simple Version that just sends some html/text. I've already Managed to set up a TCP-Server but I don't have any clue about how to "act" like an http Server.

What I did:
Created an TCP-Server. When a client Connects a TCP-Socket is created. Then I implemented a ReadyRead SLOT which gots executed when the Browser sends the "GET" Request to the Server.

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 127.0.0.1:8889
>   User-Agent:
>   Mozilla/5.0...

Then I run following Code

```
QByteArray header = "HTTP/ 1.1 200 OK\r\n";
m_Client->write(header);

QByteArray ContentType = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
m_Client->write(ContentType);

QByteArray Body = "Test";
m_Client->write(Body);

m_Client->close();
```

But what I see in the Browser is

> HTTP/ 1.1 200 OK
>  Content-Type: text/html
>  Test

So what am I doing wrong? I thought about receiving the Client GET Request, sending the Header, Mimes and the Content in Return and Then Closing the Connection.... Is this Method wrong or Just the way I coded it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space between the `/` and `1.1`, and you are missing an empty line between the headers block and the response body.

Comment: Thanks that was fast and worked perfectly..... I'm almost feeling ashamed that it has been this easy ;)

Comment: Next time check out your output a little more carefully against the specs, computers aren't really forgiving about errors in communication protocols. =)

Comment: sure ;) I also created another Question for The MJPEG Part. As For now I'm only able to send static images. Perhaps you can help me out a second time ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064955/how-to-create-a-http-mjpeg-streaming-server-with-qtcp-server-sockets